# Titanium Window removes child views

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I create a window A in Titanium (latest ver) and add some views which works well.

```
    var winA = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        backgroundColor: bgColor,
        statusBarHidden:true
    });

    var circle = createDragCircle('Dent'); //This is a Ti.Draggable view
    winA.add(circle);
```

I then open a modal window B i.e:

```
    winB.open({modal: true});
```

The winB opens fine but as it's, opening all the winA child views I've added are removed. I can tell it isn't reloading the winA.

Is this default behaviour?

**Edit:**

OK. On further investigation, it's not removing the added views. It resets them to the position they were at before the drag event. Essentially, I'm doing the following:

```
    var drag = require('ti.draggable'); 

    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
       backgroundColor: bgColor,
       statusBarHidden:true
    });

    var circle = drag.createView({
        height: 30,
        width: 30,
        zIndex: 100,
        top: top,
        left: 25,
        minLeft: 65,
        maxLeft: 285,
        minTop: 105,
        maxTop: 370,            
        isDragged: false,
        type: type
    });

    //Add an event listener to catch drag end
    circle.addEventListener('end', function(e) {
        var editwin; //Call to create winB
        editwin.open({modal: true});
    });
```

winB opens fine but the circle object moves back to the place it was before it was dragged.

Comment: Might need to have more code here.  This is missing the code that shows winA even being opened to display.  Missing the definition of winB.  Did you add the same views you added to winA to winB?  What is happening between these calls?  It is not default behavior that opening another window removes the views from a previous window.

Comment: I think that your question is related to navigation, am i correct?this is the correct behavior i think, if you want to reload the last view you catch the back button event and reload the previous view (android) on iOS you can use the native navigation group or you can check the new cross platform nav. group here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/08/a-cross-platform-navigation-group.html?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRojuaTAZKXonjHpfsXw4ukuUKO%2BlMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4CRcZmI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFTLPDMa5o0LgFXBA%3D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help all.

I sorted it out by doing the following:

```
    circle.addEventListener('end', function(e) {
        this.top = e.source.top;
        this.left = e.source.left;
    });
```

This forces the object to take on the drop top & left properties.

Answer (score 0):

if you are opening winB within winA with modal property then it will create a problem.

Comment: I am doing this. What sort of problems should I expect.

Comment: ok so as you state in your question that winB opens fine but when you open winB then it will recreate all the objects so you need to store a position of circle in a global variable and set that position to the circle object.